# To find the values of $p$ for which the given integral converges

Tags: convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

The integral we're dealing with, is $\int ^\infty_0 \frac{1-e^x}{x^p} dx$

I've a couple of questions, apart from how to determine the values of $p$ for which the integral converges -

1. Is it okay to use the **Taylor expansion** of $e^x$ here? Why, or why not? 
   If the expansion is used, what we end up with is an infinite series which can integrated (at least in an indefinite manner).
2. **When is it alright to switch integrals and sums, especially when we're dealing with improper integrals and infinite sums**?

Is (1) the right approach for this problem? (feels like the integral converges for no value of $p$, if I'm right)

Please help me out here, any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: The fact that $ x^p = e^{p\ln x} $ could be helpful.

Comment: The integrand becomes unbounded as $x\to\infty$ no matter the value of $p$ so the integral cannot converge.

Comment: Could you have a typo?  I think the numerator should have an $e^{-x}$ instead.

Comment: Nope, this was an extension of that problem. I think for the one you mention, @Omnomnomnom p<2 suffices for convergence.